# Bash in Cygwin creating folder with unknown character

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

I'm baffled.  I've got a linux backup script I used when I used to use linux as my main OS.  Now that I've moved to windows, I want to keep using it under cygwin.  I've ported it over, but am seeing a peculiar issue.

As you'll see in the code below, basically I create a folder structure /device/backups/machinename/.  I've generalized it so it determines machine name via `hostname`.  If the folder structure doesn't exist, it creates it.  What I'm seeing is that the script is generally working, but it occasionally likes to create a duplicate machine name folder with an odd square character after it.  This character shows as a question mark in cygwin.  So, I'd see:  /device/backups/machinename  and /device/backups/machinename? at the same time.  Cygwin seems to get confused between these two folders, sometimes backing up to the first and sometimes backing up to the second.  It also doesn't create this folder consistently, but if I let things run every day for a week, it'll show up.

Also note it's designed to run on a per folder basis, folder names passed in as arguments.  Keeps a week of archives in the format FolderName.0.tar.gz, FolderName.1.tar.gz, etc.

I'm going to try to work around it by hard coding the machine name for now, but I'm really interested in figuring out what the problem is.  Here's my script's source:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Backup Docs 

for FOLDER in $@
do

# Location of folder to be backed up
FOLDERLOCATION="/home/sean"
# Mount point of the backup device
DEVICE="/cygdrive/f"
# Hostname of the machine being backed up
HOSTNAME=`hostname`
      # NOTE: when I originally posted this question, the above line read:
      # HOSTNAME=`txtmsgbreakup`
      # which doesn't make any sense.  I failed at changing the hard-coded solution back 
      # to the original command that produces the string "txtmsgbreakup" (my system's name)

BACKUPFOLDER="$FOLDERLOCATION/$FOLDER/"
BACKUPDEST="$DEVICE/backups/$HOSTNAME/$FOLDER/"

# Check to see if device is mounted
if [ -d $DEVICE ]
then
    # Create directory if necessary
    if [ ! -d $BACKUPDEST ]; then
        mkdir -p $BACKUPDEST
    fi

    # Capture before time for logging
    before=$(date +%s)

    # First, tar up the old into file named after day of week
    DOW=`date +%w`
    FILENAME="$DEVICE/backups/$HOSTNAME/$FOLDER.$(( ($DOW+6)%7 )).tar.gz"
    if [ -e $FILENAME ]; then
        rm $FILENAME
    fi
    tar -czPf $FILENAME $BACKUPDEST

    # Now perform the backup
    rsync -a --del --ignore-errors $BACKUPFOLDER $BACKUPDEST
    after=$(date +%s)

    # Calculate how long the backup took
    elapsed_seconds=$(($after-$before))
    es=$((elapsed_seconds % 60))
    em=$(( (elapsed_seconds / 60) % 60 ))
    eh=$((elapsed_seconds / 3600 ))

    # Write it all to the system log
    echo "$(date) - $BACKUPFOLDER backed up.  Elapsed time:  $(printf '%02d:%02d:%02d' $eh $em $es)" >> /var/log/backup

else
    #External is not mounted if this branch is executed, log this.  
    echo "$(date) - $BACKUPFOLDER not backed up:  Backup device not mounted." >> /var/log/backup
fi

done
```

Comment: I should add:  Backup device is an external HDD formatted NTFS.

Comment: is this part of a startup script, that the device is still mounting when the script starts? (not likely, but just an idea). you can use `ls -d ${BACKUPFOLDER}* | od --format=m` may help by showing what the odd-ball character. Good luck.

Comment: `ls -b` should also show what the weird character is.  Since you're on Windows, I'd guess it's a carriage return (\r) since Windows tends to use \r\n to terminate lines.  If you've edited the script with a Windows editor, you'll need to purge the \r's from it.  Another possibility is that `txtmsgbreakup` produces Windows-style output, in which case you'll need to clean its output before using it.

Comment: `ls | cat -A` should be enough to show you what the funny character is.  `ls` usually renders non-printable characters as `?`, but if its output is redirected it shows them literally; `cat -A` translates an ASCII CR character to `^M` (to pick a decidedly non-random example).

Comment: Made a stupid mistake changing the script back to its original form.  I had solved the problem by hardcoding HOSTNAME="txtmsgbreakup" rather than HOSTNAME=`hostname`.  I changed it back to HOSTNAME=`txtmsgbreakup` which is invalid.  The script never ran like that, it was only an error in what I posted, so that's not the problem.

Comment: I also suspected a CR, and I'll take a look to see what the actual character is soon.  However, even if it IS a CR, why would it only happen on rare occasion?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `HOSTNAME=`txtmsgbreakup

If you want to put a string, try that : **HOSTNAME="txtmsgbreakup"** or if you'd want the dynamic hostname, the variable **$HOSTNAME** is already in your environment.

In my understanding of your problem, you'd want to define HOSTNAME with the string "txtmsgbreakup" but while you put it inside backticks **`**, you ask to run a command that is not exists.

Morevover, use more quotes in your shell variables to avoid things breaking (someday)

Comment: Yeah, I'm a moron.  I had changed my script to hardcode "txtmsgbreakup" as you suggest, but changed it back to the original for this example.  I changed the quotes to ticks, but forgot to change the string to "hostname".  So that line is actually `hostname` and not `txtmsgbreakup`, which evaluates to "txtmsgbreakup" on my particular machine.  Sorry.  I'll edit the original question too.